# How does Ruby solve the method lookup in 'diamond' mixin?

Tags: ruby

The version of Ruby is this:

```
% ruby -v
ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-darwin17]
```

I came upon the idea that what if we do mixins in the 'diamond' form in Ruby.

Here is an example:

```
module M3; end
module M1
  prepend M3
end

module M2
  prepend M3
end

class Base
  include M1
  include M2
end

p Base.ancestors # [Base, M3, M2, M1, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

The result is `[Base, M3, M2, M1, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`.

Even if you change mixin type of the module `M2` from `include` to `prepend` in the `Base` class, the result is the same:

```
module M3; end
module M1
  prepend M3
end

module M2
  prepend M3
end

class Base
  include M1
  prepend M2 # <= change mixin type
end

p Base.ancestors # [Base, M3, M2, M1, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

The result is also `[Base, M3, M2, M1, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`. It looks strange to me.

How does Ruby solve the method lookup in 'diamond' mixin?

Note) I have already understood the basics of method lookup in Ruby, https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/trunk/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html#label-Method+Lookup.

Comment: _"It looks strange to me"_ - what would you expect the result to be in the second case?

Comment: The `prepend` keyword indicates that the mixined module (M2) is prior to the owner (Base), so it is expected to be `[M3, M2, Base, M3, M1]` or `[M3, M2, Base, M1]` or `[M2, Base, M3, M1]` in the second case. I thought it's strange in that the former and the latter example is exactly the same output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that:

- `include` and `prepend` establishes a partial relation (ancestor relation) among the relevant modules/classes at each step, and
- An ancestor relation cannot be contradicted in a later step.

Let us start with:

```
module M1; end
module M2; end
module M3; end
class Base; end
```

and follow each step. The first three steps should be trivial:

```
Base.ancestors
#=> [Base, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

M1.prepend M3
M1.ancestors
# => [M3, M1]

M2.prepend M3
M2.ancestors
#=> [M3, M2]
```

Now, your crucial first step is `Base.include M1`. This inserts the ancestors of `M1` (the whole `[M3, M1]` chunk) just to the right of `Base` before `Object`:

```
Base.include M1
Base.ancestors
#=> [Base, M3, M1, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

The next step is `Base.prepend M2`. This attempts to insert the ancestors of `M2` (the whole `[M3, M2]` chunk) just to the left of `Base`. But notice that that would cause a contradictory relation between `Base` and `M3`.

```
Base.prepend M2
Base.ancestors
#=> Cannot be [M3, M2, Base, M3, M1, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Since it has already been established that `M3` appears on the right side of `Base`, the best it can do to place `[M3, M2]` is to place it on the right side of `Base`:

```
Base.prepend M2
Base.ancestors
#=> [Base, M3, M2, M1, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

It may appear that placing `M2` on the right side of `Base` contradicts the intention of `Base.prepend M2`. But that can be canceled/modified to fit on the spot, whereas an already established relation between `Base` and `M3` cannot be canceled in a later spot.

In fact, when there is no way to satisfy the relations already established, then an error is raised:

```
module M4; end
module M5; end
M4.include M5
M5.include M4 #>> ArgumentError: cyclic include detected
```

Comment: I see. Ancestor relations, or directions are always kept anytime we mix-in modules. I tried other cases and roughly understood. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of things that might help here. One is to recall the default behaviour of `include` and `prepend` is that that they only add the module if it has not already been added to this module or one of its ancestors.

Next, is to look at what happens as 2 separate steps rather than performing the `include M1` and `prepend M2` all in one go.

With your module definitions as in the question, if we just have:

```
class Base
  include M1
end
```

`Base.ancestors` is now `[Base, M3, M1, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]`, which is probably what you'd expect.

Next, if we do

```
class Base
  prepend M2
end
```

`Base.ancestors` is now `[Base, M3, M2, M1, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]`

The reason is that `M2` prepends `M3` but `M3` is already in `Base`'s ancestors so `M3`'s position remains unchanged. However, because `M2` prepends `M3` this means `M2` must come *after* `M3`. The result is that `M2` appears after `M3` rather than as the first entry, even though it is being prepended in `Base`.

Answer (score 1):

While both existing answers here are pretty logical and explain everything great, I would also just drop a reference to the documentation:

> [...] **if this module has not already been added to mod or one of its ancestors.** [...]
>   — [`Module#prepend_features`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-prepend_features)

Emphasis is mine. That said, `prepend M`, as well as `include M` (and `extend M` for ancestors of the eigenclass) are all NOOP if the module is already found in the ancestors chain.